# Can't leverage variable for terraform pipeline in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, yaml

getting a head scratching error when trying to leverage a variable for a terraform pipeline in Azure Devops.

```
Error: Reference to undeclared input variable
│ 
│   on compute.tf line 760, in module "vm_prd_test":
│  760:   sas_token = var.sas_token
│ 
│ An input variable with the name "sas_token" has not been declared. This
│ variable can be declared with a variable "sas_token" {} block.
╵
```

I am using the custom script extension in terraform to pass through keys and a script to bootstrap virtual machines upon creation like so:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "vm-linux-extension" {
  count                = var.enable_vm_extension ? length(var.hostnames) : 0
  name                 = "${local.hostnames[count.index]}-extension"
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_virtual_machine.vm-linux[count.index].id
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions"
  type                 = "CustomScript"
  type_handler_version = "2.0"
  
  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "fileUris": ["<link to script>", "<link to key appended with sas token>?${var.sas_token}"],
        "commandToExecute": "chmod +x bootstrap.sh && sudo ${var.script_command}"
    }
SETTINGS
}
```

The idea being to pass through a link to the script and key inside of our storage account.

I also added the variable for SAS token to variables.tf

```
variable "sas_token" {
  description = "The SAS token for the blob storage"
  type        = string
}
```

I have the sas token in azure devops library variable groups with permissions to the pipeline in question

[image: Variable Group]

I also have the variable group referenced directly in the pipeline

```
- group: SAS_TOKEN_GROUP
```

and referenced again as an envirnoment variable that can be parsed by terraform during the apply stage:

```
- task: Bash@3
              displayName: 'Terraform Apply'
              env:
                TF_VAR_sas_token: $(SAS_TOKEN)
                ARM_CLIENT_ID: $(AZURE_CLIENT_ID)
                ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: $(AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET)
                ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: $(AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
                ARM_TENANT_ID: $(AZURE_TENANT_ID)
                BUILD_BUILDNUMBER: $(Build.BuildNumber)
```

I feel like ive covered all my bases in referencing this variable so that it can be securely stored and appended to the link in order to download the pem key for the bootstrapping process but i can't get past this error.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: The declaration is within the config for the declared `vm_prd_test` module?

Comment: Hey Matthew, yes I subsequently tried again with sas_token = var.sas_token within the vm_prd_test module that calls upon these modules. Same issue. @MatthewSchuchard

Comment: That would imply the answer to my question is "no" rather than "yes" though, and that would also be root cause for the error.

Comment: @MatthewSchuchard not sure I follow. Within the vm_prd_test module, I define sas_token - var.sas_token. Given that I have the value inside an Azure devops variable group, I shouldn’t have to explicitly define it inside of the vm module correct?

Comment: You can run the same terraform scripts on your local machine to check whether it has the same issue or not. If it has the same error, it may be related to your terraform scripts.  You can also try to set a value for "TF_VAR_sas_token" directly in the Bash task without using variable group for the time being.  And then check if it has the same error or not. If it works, the issue may be related to variable group.

Answer (score 0):

This error essentially means that inside the module `"vm_prd_test"`, Terraform is unable to find the variable `sas_token`.

##### Part done from your end:

1. You've declared the `sas_token` variable in `variables.tf`.
2. You've set up the Azure DevOps pipeline with an environment variable `TF_VAR_sas_token` which should pass the value of the `SAS_TOKEN` to Terraform.
3. You're using the `sas_token` variable inside the `azurerm_virtual_machine_extension` resource, which seems to be outside of the `"vm_prd_test"` module.

##### Major Issue:

**Module Declaration**: If `sas_token` is being used inside a module (as the error indicates with `"vm_prd_test"`), you need to make sure that when you're calling the module, you're passing the variable to it.

I was trying to understand your requirement and tried to make a demo version of this.

##### My file structure:

```
├── main.tf
├── variables.tf
└── modules
    └── vm_prd_test
        ├── main.tf
        └── variables.tf
```

##### main.tf:

```
 provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "vm-linux-extension" {
  count                = var.enable_vm_extension ? length(var.hostnames) : 0
  name                 = "${local.hostnames[count.index]}-extension"
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_virtual_machine.vm-linux[count.index].id
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions"
  type                 = "CustomScript"
  type_handler_version = "2.0"
  
  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "fileUris": ["<link to script>", "<link to key appended with sas token>?${var.sas_token}"],
        "commandToExecute": "chmod +x bootstrap.sh && sudo ${var.script_command}"
    }
SETTINGS
}

module "vm_prd_test" {
  source    = "./modules/vm_prd_test"
  sas_token = var.sas_token
}
```

##### variables.tf:

```
variable "sas_token" {
  description = "The SAS token for the blob storage"
  type        = string
}
```

**modules/blob_module/main.tf**:

```
 resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm_prd_test" {
  name                  = "myVM"
  location              = "East US"
  resource_group_name   = "some-resource-group"
  vm_size               = "Standard_DS1_v2"

  storage_os_disk {
    name          = "myOsDisk"
    caching       = "ReadWrite"
    create_option = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Premium_LRS"
  }

  storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "16.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "hostname"
    admin_username = "admin"
    admin_password = "Password1234!"
  }

  os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = false
  }

  network_interface_ids = ["some_network_interface_id"]

  tags = {
    environment = "production"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo ${var.sas_token}"
  }
}
```

**modules/blob_module/variables.tf**:

```
variable "sas_token" {
  description = "The SAS token for the blob storage"
  type        = string
}

variable "account_name" {
  description = "The name of the storage account."
  type        = string
}

variable "resource_group_name" {
  description = "The name of the resource group in which to create the storage account."
  type        = string
}
```

Now make sure you check the steps to follow for the code to provision the requirement.

**export TF_VAR_sas_token="your_sas_token_value"**

This will export the SAS token which will be used going further in the code during execution.

Then follow the commands mentioned below.

**terraform init**

**terraform apply**